# Gradle Cmdline error, Execution failed for task ':..:jar'

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I was trying to do a command line build with gradle, and I had the following in my gradle.build file.

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

I kept getting this error, funny that it was trying to build my jar in a upper directory folder.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':..:jar'.
> Failed to create directory '/home/jsiddharth/workspace/v2/working/mnoxbackendv2/build/libs'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

As soon as I commented

```
/*
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
*/
```

The build went through ok, with no issues. Can you help me find out why this happened ? Compatibility has nothing to do with creation of jar's I suppose ?

> Note : I need to build this jar with backward 1.7 compatibility since Android has still not migrated to 1.8.

Comment: Compatibility doesn't, but notice how you've also commented out the `apply plugin: 'java'` directive as well, so none of your projects are java projects anymore.  Did you try running the build with `--info` or `--stacktrace` as the error helpfully suggests?

Comment: I have apply plugin java in the begining of the file..

Comment: the error helpfully suggest that permission is not granted for creating teh jar in that location. But, why is gradle trying to create the jar in ../ folder ?

Comment: If you are using a multi-project try to put the plugin and compatibility options in your root build.gradle

Comment: What command are you running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a multi-project try to put the plugin and compatibility options in your root build.gradle or in settings.

*(NOTE here it might iterate through something that is considered a project, therefore can't run the jar task, your project structure might be odd or something)*

You shouldn't need to use the allprojects{} project iteration closure.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories{}
dependencies {}
etc{}
```